# If Ax = 0 for every x in $R^n$, A is a zero matrix

Tags: matrices

If A is a $m$ $x$ $n$ matrix such that: $Ax = 0$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then A = 0 is the zero matrix.

I have no idea how to begin proving this. The only hint is to consider a $j$ column in the Identity matrix $I_n$, but I don't see how that helps. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: What do you get if you multiply a matrix with a vector that contains only zeros except one 1?

Comment: You can start with: assume that $\exists a_{ij}\ne 0$.

Comment: @sranthrop, don't you just get a single vector, and its value is the x in the $ij^{th}$ position (where $I_{ij} = 1$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what goes on, take an arbitrary non-zero $2\times 2$ matrix. Assume for a second all its entries are non-zero. Can you think of a single $x\in \mathbb R^2$ with $Ax\ne 0$? Now, what happens if one or more of the entries (but not all!) are zero? what can you do? Now what happens if it's an arbitrary matrix?

Comment: I can see why A must be the zero matrix when you explained it like this, but how do I give a proof of showing concretely that A is the zero matrix?

Comment: Let $A\ne 0$ be an arbitrary metric satisfying the stated property. We may assume the entry $a_{ij}\ne 0$. But then ... contradicting the given property of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The $j$th column of the matrix $A$ is the image of the $j$th coordinate vector under $A$. Now what does the question tell us about these images?